White-to-Transparent fade above Widget
I try to implement this fade effect:

I am currently using a Stack and try to put a LinearGradient above my tag-list.
My current code is like this:
Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 30,
      child: ListView.builder(
          ....my vertical scrolling tags
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.white,
                Colors.white,
                Colors.transparent,
              ],
              begin: Alignment.centerRight,
              end: Alignment.centerLeft,
              stops: [0, 0.05, 0.25],
            ),
          ),
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 30,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

But this produces this:

What am I doing wrong? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Try to wrap your arrow image in Container with boxShadow.

Instead of trying to adjust the stops, its better to align the gradient to the right using Positioned.right: 0 and then select the width of the gradient using Positioned.width.
*I didn't tested this code so you might need to adjust some properties
Stack(
  children: [
    SizedBox(
      height: 30,
      child: ListView.builder(
          ....my vertical scrolling tags
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      right: 0,
      width: 30,
      height: 30,
      child: IgnorePointer(
        child: DecoratedBox(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.white,
                Colors.transparent,
              ],
              begin: Alignment.centerRight,
              end: Alignment.centerLeft,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),

Edit
if the main problem you are trying to solve is the vertical unexpected stretch of the black color, you can wrap the Stack with ClipRect and set the height to 30 to clip the overflow
Edit
I found the solution here
replaced Colors.transparent with Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)

Thanks. Sadly I have the same problem. There is this weird black shade in the gradient. I don't understand where it is coming from as I am just fading from white to transparent. I would've expected it to be invisible when it is over white background.

@progNewbie I edited my answer with a link to the answer

Ohhh thanks! That did help. Although I don't understand why.

@progNewbie the reason it worked is because Colors.transparent is equals to Color(0x00000000) which is black with transparency and its different from Color(0x00ffffff) which is white with transparency.
